# The issue of defining size of an alphabet in an number system

Tags: numbers, system

I ask for helping with next question:
I've got difficulties when studying the question.
The difficulties is that, firstly, i can't understand the building of the thought line when we define the set of number alphabet (example 0,1,2...9)
Nk  =  Pk + 1 / Pk, if Pk+1  /  Pk divided completely, else (Pk+1 / Pk) + 1
It's the way of defining the set of alphabet in any position number system. Could you please make the representation with commentary of the line.  In common case how it will be looking if one encounters with the task of defining such a set